# CLLocationManager does not send location to the didUpdateLocations method

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am working on an `iOS 6.1 iPhone app` with `ARC` enabled which will be using a `CLLocationManager` to track the devices position.

**UPDATE**

I have a `DestinationViewController` which implements the `CLLocationManagerDelegate`. It creates the `CLLocationManager` and does the setup. I have imported the `CoreLocation framework` to my project.

I have tried to debug a lot and can see that the `CLLocationManager` is created and no errors are present. But the problem is that the `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` is `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`
both before `[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];` and also *after*.
So there is no prompt about asking permission to use location services for this app. Because of that this method is never fired.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:  
(NSArray *)locations
```

I have also tried to search the web for hours to look for similar examples but with no luck. Code from DestinationViewController is posted below.

Interface

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface DestinationViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

Implementation

```
#import "DestinationViewController.h"

@interface DestinationViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@end


@implementation DestinationViewController

// Initializer
- (CLLocationManager *)locationManager
{
    if (!_locationManager) {
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    }
    return _locationManager;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self startLocation];
}


- (void)startLocation
{
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 1;

    NSString *error;
    if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        error = @"Error message";
    }

    CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted ||
        status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied ||) {
        error = @"Error message";
    }

    if (error) {
        NSLog(error);
    }
    else
    {

        status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;

        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

        status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

        NSLog(@"CLLocationManager is %@", self.locationManager);
        NSLog(@"Location is %@", self.locationManager.location);

        [self updateUI];
    }
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *recentLocation = [locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"Found location");
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError");
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    NSLog(@"Change in authorization status");
}
```

Comment: Is this on the simulator or device? If simulator, have you allowed XCode to emulate the location?

Comment: Have tried both. I have created a custom location and tried to do the Freeway drive also

Comment: Can you try implementing the deprecated `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` and see if that gets called?

Comment: I have tried that also. 
Actually now my simulator says "Cannot Determine Location" when i try to run the Apple Maps app. If i look in Settings the apps are allowed to get the location.

Comment: did you check and see what kind of error you get in "didFailWithError" ? because that would help in determining why your method is not fired.

Comment: THat method is never called. Have placed a breakpoint inside it and it does not fire. CLAuthorizationStatus is set to kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined both before and after startUpdatingLocation is called. How come no alert is shown to the user?

Comment: Why are you doing this: `_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];[self setLocationManager:self.locationManager];`? That looks suspicious to me.

Comment: Sorry but i can`t see that line of code. Do you mean 
`if (!_locationManager) {
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    }
    return _locationManager;`  ?

Comment: @AndersFriis You completely rewrote the code in your question and removed that part.

Comment: Oh sorry you saw it while i was editing it.

Answer (score -14, accepted):

I finally solved it! My delegate wasn't set properly.
Instead of doing:

`self.locationManager.delegate = self;`

I changed it to:

`[self.locationManager setDelegate:self];`

And now my delegate methods get fired.

Thanks to those who helped!

Comment: I've never had this be a problem :/

Comment: I (also) doubt this has/had anything to do with it.

Answer (score 7):

Your code should work.

Make sure your application is authorized to use location services.

You can use following method to check authorization status in code

```
 + (CLAuthorizationStatus)authorizationStatus
```

Edit

kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined is most likely caused by location services being disabled. You should check location services status first. Code should be like this

```
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
    // Location Services Are Enabled
    switch([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]) {
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
            // User has not yet made a choice with regards to this application
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
            // This application is not authorized to use location services.  Due
            // to active restrictions on location services, the user cannot change
            // this status, and may not have personally denied authorization
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
            // User has explicitly denied authorization for this application, or
            // location services are disabled in Settings
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
            // User has authorized this application to use location services
            break;
    }
} else {
    // Location Services Disabled
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did the following: 
     CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
And in the debugger i can see that it is kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized. So it should work but the method still doesn't get called.

Comment: After debugging a lot i can see that when i'm running the app on my iPhone 5, its `CLAuthorizationStatus` is set to `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` both before and after `startUpdatingLocation` is called. How come no alert is shown to the user?

Comment: The apple documentation for `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`  states that "The user has not yet made a choice regarding whether this application can use location services."
So it can`t be disabled. I can´t find my app in the Privacy Settings in Location Services. Do you know why it doesn`t show up there?

Comment: kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined means user has not made its choice but I have seen sources which claim that it can occur when location services being enabled for the app but not turned on the device. Are you sure location services are enabled under setting->Privacy->location services on device?

Comment: Yeah it is on. I`m testing on my iPhone 5 which can easily find it's location in Maps app. But my app isn't in the list of apps using location services?

Comment: See the description and notes of kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined constant at http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1830485

Comment: try setting locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO; and make sure you have CFBundleDisplayName (bundle display name) key in your project plist file. It should not be empty, so location alert can get bundle display name.

Comment: I have set the Bundle display name and now i can see it in the location service settings on my Simulator but NOT on my iPhone 5. Should the `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` be set before the `startUpdatingLocation`?

Comment: yes pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically should be called bofore the startUpdatingLocation. Also update your iOS SDK and xcode to latest version (4.6.1).

Comment: Updated my xcode and SDK and added the `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` but it is still the same.

Comment: Did anyone ever figure out what was the issue with this? Running into this now and have no idea why it's stuck on kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined.