# Xcode 5 didupdatelocations not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode5, xcode5.0.1

I'm following this tutorial for creating a program that shows the location of a user. I've told Xcode to simulate a location for me already, and even on the simulator made sure it was allowing my application to keep track of locations. However, nothing is being logged to my console.

The header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface WhereamiViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

@end
```

And the main file:

```
#import "WhereamiViewController.h"

@implementation WhereamiViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        [locationManager setDelegate:self];
        [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
        [locationManager setPausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically:NO];
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [locations lastObject]);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}

@end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CLLocationManager does not send location to the didUpdateLocations method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656889/cllocationmanager-does-not-send-location-to-the-didupdatelocations-method)

Comment: @josh It works if I put my code into viewDidLoad, but not when its in initWithNibName. Why is that? Originally initWithNibName wasn't even called so I set it in my AppDelegate.m `WhereamiViewController *wvc = [[WhereamiViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WhereamiViewController" bundle:nil];`

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure about the answer but this is what i have got.
iOS 7 allows location fetch only when app is in foreground.
When you write your code in `initwithNibName`, your app is not actually in foreground it is creating controls from xib files and all.That is why OS is not giving you the location updates.

Comment: That did it for me. I called `startUpdatingLocation` during first tests from `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, which seemingly is too early. After calling it from a button-press everything worked as expected.